# how does S3TransferManager.uploadDirectory upload files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager, s3transfermanager

does S3TransferManager.uploadDirectory uploads one file at a time using multiple threads or multiple files at a time using multiple threads? I am going thru what's mentioned [here](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/transfer/s3/S3TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory(software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.model.UploadDirectoryRequest)) but it doesn't mention about this. Please advise.